# How to communicate between 2 framework / library

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, swift-framework

I have one module in one application say chat module now I want to take it into another application (By creating a framework or library not by dragging and dropping its classes to other applications). How can I do this?

for Eg:
I have one framework called network framework which has methods:

```
func GetDataFromAPI()->Data
```

Now I want to create another framework say Chat, Settings, Live Status etc framework. I want to develop it in a way that I can use it in my other projects as well. For this, I have used Swift package manager and created one separate framework for each (Network, Chat, Settings, Live Status etc). Now my problem is I have to call API in each framework to get data but my api calls is written in network module. so my question are as follows.

a) How can I access this network module in another framework?
b) Do I need to import this network module in all other modules? If yes then how ? If no then what will be the best way to do with such kind of problem?

[image]

Comment: A Swift Package can have dependencies, so I'd use dependencies between each module.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/swift-packages/  https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/410/

Comment: Is there any way where i can play with references of one module into another one ?

Comment: @Kanishka What you mean by "can play"? Make an empty folder and create all needed packages in it. Then you can "play" with references between them. Actually, an SPM package is just a folder with Package.swift manifest inside.